# Text widget not displaying the contents of what's in a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I want a page in my program to display the contents of a list created by a function, but when I put the address of the list in the "insert" function it doesn't work and shows an error message whenever I click on Start, "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple", trying to get to the next page.

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import random

title_font= ("Microsoft Jhenghei UI Light", 35)


class MathsApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand= True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.title("Maths Revision App")
        self.geometry("800x500")
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, q1):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        #funtion that displays different pages

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.configure(bg ="white")
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome!", font=title_font, bg="white", fg="#004d99")
        lbl.place(x=30, y=20)        
        rtbtn=tk.Button(self, text="Start", height=3, width=15, fg="white", bg="#004d99", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(q1))
        rtbtn.place(x=350, y=200)    

class q1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.configure(bg="white")        
        lbl=Label(self, text="Question 1", font=("Microsoft Jhenghei UI Light", 35), bg="white", fg="#004d99")
        lbl.place(x=30, y=20)
        txt=Text(self, height=5, width=70)
        txt.config(state="normal")
        #where I am trying to display the contents of the list
        txt.insert(tk.INSERT,qlist[0,0])
        txt.config(state="disabled")
        txt.place(x=35,y=125)
        nxt=Button(self, text="Next", height=3, width=15, fg="white", bg="#004d99")
        nxt.place(x=650, y=400)
        ans=Entry(self)
        ans.place(x=650, y=350,height=25)

#function for creating the list
qlist=0
def getQuestions():
    global qlist
    qlist=[0,0,0,0,0]
    noschosen=[]
    with open("questiontest.txt","r") as f:
        lines=f.read().strip().split("\n")
    i=0
    while i<len(qlist):
        chosen=False
        n=random.randint(1,20)
        while n in noschosen:
            n=random.randint(1,20)
        qline=2*n-1
        noschosen.append(n)
        qlist[i]=(lines[qline],lines[qline+1])
        i=i+1
getQuestions()



print (qlist)
app = MathsApp()
app.mainloop()
```

The txt file is called "questiontest" and contains:

```
.
Question1
Answer1
Question2
Answer2
Question3
Answer3
Question4
Answer4
Question5
Answer5
Question6
Answer6
Question7
Answer7
Question8
Answer8
Question9
Answer9
Question10
Answer10
Question11
Answer11
Question12
Answer12
Question13
Answer13
Question14
Answer14
Question15
Answer15
Question16
Answer16
Question17
Answer17
Question18
Answer18
Question19
Answer19
Question20
Answer20
```

On the second page it should display "QuestionX" in the text box (X representing whatever number). I know that there is something in the address because I make the code print the entire list before running the GUI.

Comment: What is `qlist[0,0]` supposed to do?  You can't index a list with a tuple like that.  Perhaps you meant `qlist[0][0]`?

Comment: What is the error message you are seeing?

Comment: The error message was "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple". It was because of what Jason mentioned (qlist[0,0] instead of qlist[0][0]), my code works now. Thank you both for the help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message.

Comment: My bad, it's in there now.